# Firebase Functions Cannot read property 'databaseURL'

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I keep getting the following errors in my Firebase Functions log

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'databaseURL' of undefined at repoManagerDatabaseFromApp

Here is my code not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
exports.dynamicMetaTagsUpdate = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  console.log("dynamicMetaTagsUpdate Called");

  const html = fs.readFileSync("./index.html", "utf8");
  const {id} = request.query;
  const botDetector = new BotDetector();
  const userAgent = request.headers["user-agent"].toString();
  const bot = botDetector.parse(userAgent);
  if (bot || DEBUG_BOT) {
    try {
      console.log("try");

      const dbRef = firebase.database().ref("https://wiijii-visualizations-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");
      dbRef.child("charts").child(id).get().then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          console.log(snapshot.val());
        } else {
          console.log("No data available");
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

      return response.send(html);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return response.send(html);
    }
  }
  return response.send(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got working here is my code

```
console.log("try");
      const ref = admin.database().ref("charts");
      console.log("ref");
      console.log(ref);

      ref.child(id).get().then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          console.log(snapshot.val());
        } else {
          console.log("No data available");
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) in a Cloud function and not the client SDK. When you use `admin.database()`, it returns the Database service for the default app. That essentially means you will get database instance of the Firebase project you have deployed the Cloud function too.

```ts
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"

// Default app
admin.initializeApp()
const database = admin.database()
```

You need to pass any arguments in those methods only if you are using multiple Firebase projects (or Admin SDK instances) in a single Cloud function. You can find more about initializing multiple instances in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps) if needed.